# How do I call the InsertionSort method here?

Tags: c++, vector, methods, stl

I have the following code.. The method should work but I'm having trouble passing the vector to a function. I searched around and found that vector can be passed as 'references' or 'values' and I tried both, but they didn't seem to work. Am I calling the method incorrectly or passing the vector in a wrong way? Either ways, what can I do to fix this? Thanks! :)

```
//insertion sort method

#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n){ 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

int temp = arr[i]; // element adjacent to left sorted array 
int j = i - 1; 

while(temp > arr[j] && j != 0){
    arr[j] = arr[j - 1]; 
    j--; 
}
arr[j] = temp; 
}
}

int main(){ 
int n, temp; 
cin >> n; 
vector <int> arr; 

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
cin >> temp; 
arr.push_back(temp); 
}

insertionSort(arr, n); 

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
cout << arr[i] << " "; 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: change your function definition header to *void insertionSort(vector<int> &arr, int n)*, array of integer and vector of integers are different data types and you can't pass a vector to a function expecting an array of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the insertionSort(int arr[], int n) method is wrong.
You also processed the arr incorrectly. At first iteration, int j = 0 - 1 = -1; which is unexpected/ out of bound.

Please try this :

```
void insertionSort(vector <int> &arr, int n){

    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (temp<arr[j]))
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot Monirul :)